# MVC, How tell what model data is being sent from the server to the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using MVC EF and Kendo UI, however I'm interested in knowing what model data is being sent from the server to the client.

I have a suspicion the models are being eagerly loaded (if that's the right term) and more is being transferred than I'd like.

Is there anyway to tell what data is being sent from the server to the client?

Comment: Sql Profiler is what you want, has nothing to do with models... or MVC..

Comment: Thanks, and i know where your coming from, however id still like to be able to see whats actually being sent to the client (if that's possible)

Comment: How are you loading the data into your Kendo UI controls? Are you loading it async from a URL?

Comment: I the standard model in the views, additionally i have async ajax calls, i just thought there might be an easy way of looking at what data is getting sent to the client for both model and async calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to use SQL profiler to monitor the SQL being executed against the database. This will allow you to view the SQL generated by, and executed on behalf of, the Entity Framework. You can then copy the SQL from SQL Profiler and manually run it within SQL Management Studio (or something similar) and you can check that the data being returned from the database is what you expected.

If you are loading data into your Kendo UI controls using an async call to a URL, then you can use Fiddler to monitor what data is being sent to/from the URLs of your web application. Within Fiddler you can then view your data, i.e. the data returned from the URL, as XML or JSON (depending on how
you have setup your MVC application).

If you are returning a view from your URL you can still view the response from the URL within Fiddler, but you will find that the contents of the response will be a mixture of HTML, etc, and your data.

So basically for async calls you can use Fiddler and for "model" calls you can either use the SQL profiler approach or do a ToList() on your LINQ, place a breakpoint and look at the contents of the list from within Visual Studio.